# jQuery Draggable jumps down when dragging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a draggable window. The draggable window jumps down A LOT when I try to drag it. Any ideas why?

http://jsfiddle.net/t4yN3/

```
$("#draggable").draggable();
```

**CSS**

```
#draggable {
    width:450px; 
    height:300px; 
    overflow:scroll; 
    position:absolute; 
    padding-top:8px; 
    background:#333; 
    border:2px solid purple; 
    z-index:9999999; 
    color: white;
}
```

Really weird. Scroll down and try to drag it.

**ANSWERED. READ COMMENT**

Comment: Okay I found the problem... jQuery was apparently too old, so updating to 2.0.3 works... VERY WEIRD.

Comment: Answer yourself this question, not in the comments, and mark it as best answer ;)

Comment: I couldn't do that because I did not check the "Answer this yourself" or whatever it was ;)

Comment: Add an answer with the solution and click the check :)